# Lotus Notes 8: Choosing to which email address (within same contact) an email goes to

Tags: lotus-notes

Question moved from StackOverflow (was posted there erroneously)
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11651114/choosing-to-which-email-address-within-same-contact-an-email-goes-to

All,

This might sound like a very simple question but I am new to Lotus Notes 8 and nobody around me seems to know an answer to it.

As most people, I keep multiple email addresses per contact (ie.: their work and personal email). (example: john.doe@company.com and john.doe@gmail.com; both these email addresses under "John Doe" contact).

When I go to send an email to "John Doe" Lotus Notes 8 just displays "John Doe" on the "To:" field without informing me as to which of both email addresses is the email going to go to.

Does anyone know how I can show / choose which email address is the email going to be send to?

Thanks in advance

m

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer may only be valid in Notes 8.5 or later. I use 8.5.3 UP1.

While you are doing type ahead, the contacts name appears below the send to field. If there are multiple addresses the primary one is displayed and a "twisty" is shown at the right side. Mousing over the name expands the twisty to show and allow selection of alternate emails. Here is a sample (with my spouse's email redacted.:-) )

[image]

Enjoy

/Newbs

Comment: That email is still fairly easy to read... a plain black block or a pixelized blur are usually best for redacting screenshots.

Comment: Newbs, I do not see this on my version of Lotus notes (Release 8.0.2) any other alternative?

Comment: macutan This is the answer. If it's not in 8.0.2 your only alternative is to use multiple contacts or just upgrade. It's clearly a feature IBM added later, so you're not going to find a magic solution. This doesn't work in the nlnotes.exe client either, which is the one I use, or did use until Newbs made that awesome post. :) +1 @Newbs GIMP is super handy for the pixelize filter, and it's open source.

Comment: @Lie Ryan: You are probably right. Just, please do not spam her. If you do she will probably take it out on me.

Comment: @rtanner: You are correct. This feature uses capabilities that Eclipse adds to the Notes client. The answer is upgrade. Alternative mail templates at OpenNtf.org might have a feature for this which will work in the Basic Client (nlnotes/exe).

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot upgrade. Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1):

Lotus Notes defaults to the Business email field. You can view this by clicking E-mail with the contact open.
[image]

As far as I know there isn't a way to switch this on the fly, short of creating multiple contacts for the same person under different email addresses.

Comment: thank you r.tanner. I was aware of that selection but I was wondering if there is an option somewhere that would let me pick one...